# Display data from firebase Realtime Database in a recyclerview kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display my products data from firebase but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

**HomeActivity**

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var productsRef: DatabaseReference? = null
private var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)


    productsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Products")



override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()



    val options = productsRef.let {
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Products>()
            .setQuery(it!!, Products::class.java)
            .build()
    }





    val adapter = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, ProductsViewHolder>(options) {

            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductsViewHolder, position: Int, model: Products) {



                holder.txtProductName.text = model.getPname()
                holder.txtProductDescription.text = model.getDescription()
                holder.txtProductPrice.text = "Price = " + model.getPrice() + "$"
                Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.imageView)




            }

            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductsViewHolder {

                val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.product_items_layout, parent, false)
                return ProductsViewHolder(view)
            }
        }


    adapter.startListening()
    recycler_menu.adapter = adapter

    recycler_menu.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recycler_menu.layoutManager = layoutManager

}

}
```

**ProductsViewHolder**

```
class ProductsViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

var txtProductName: TextView = itemView.product_name
var txtProductDescription: TextView = itemView.product_description
var txtProductPrice: TextView = itemView.product_price
var imageView: ImageView = itemView.product_image

}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: that the products are not seen when starting the app, but I wanted to try to show just one and then add more

Comment: I am new to this, and I wanted to test showing only one product to see if it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a list of products in a recycler view, you need to have a **list of** products in the database. In the screenshot, we see that you have only the properties a single product under `/Products`, which isn't enough to populate a recycler view. Firebase will try to load a product from each of your individual properties (like `description` and `image`) and will fail to do so, because it tries to convert that single value to an entire product object.

---

The structure you'll need is:

```
Products: {
  "someProductId": {
    "description: "...",
    "imge: "...",
    "pname: "...",
    "price: "..."
  }
}
```

Now if you have more products, you'll have:

```
Products: {
  "someProductId": {
    "description: "...",
    "imge: "...",
    "pname: "...",
    "price: "..."
  },
  "anotherProductId": {
    "description: "...",
    "imge: "...",
    "pname: "...",
    "price: "..."
  }
}
```

And you can load it into the recycler view with the code you already have.

---

To store products in this format, you need to add an extra level to your database with the product ID. If the products have a natural ID already, you can do so with:

```
productsRef.child("someProductId").setValue(product);
```

If they don't have an ID, you can let Firebase generate one for you with:

```
productsRef.push().setValue(product);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice tutorial on FirebaseRecyclerAdapter [here](https://medium.com/android-grid/how-to-use-firebaserecycleradpater-with-latest-firebase-dependencies-in-android-aff7a33adb8b). I haven used up since I built my custom adapter with a firebase listener. I guess you will have the same result.

P.S You are assigning twice the layoutManager

Usually initialization is the following:

```
//Setup recycler view
    viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    viewAdapter = YourAdapter( ... )

    recyclerView = view!!.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
    recyclerView.apply {
        layoutManager = viewManager
        adapter = viewAdapter
    }
```